# show the rate of tax in order

Tags: commerce

I've create Tax Rate of 20% in VAT type of tax.

It is now displayed in the checkout process and in order view.

What I want now is to show the rate i have created, which is 20%, in the checkout and in order?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want to do but could you just not rename the display name of your tax to 20%?

Go to admin/commerce/config/taxes click edit on your tax and under display title enter 20% tax or what you wish the display name to be.

Comment: Yes that's right! I saw it awhile ago, I did not put any in that textbox because it says it will get the value of the previous textbox if left empty.. CHEERS! Thank you for the quick repLy though.